# rewrite rule with regex to add forward slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to know how can I turn this url :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/online/param1/param2
```

Into

```
https://www.mywebsite.com//online/param1/param2
```

Or into

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/en/online/param1/param2
```

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# case 1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s//
RewriteRule ^(online/.*)$ //$1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]

# case 2
RewriteRule ^(online/.*)$ /en/$1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]
```

Comment: That seems to work for case 2, thanks :) How can I make it work for case one ?